# Loops to read specific columns from CSVs, skip when absent

Tags: r, csv, lapply

I have hundreds of csv files with different types of environmental data. E.g. They heading all have the columns [sensor_id], [sensor_type], [timestamp], [long], [lat]. Some have another column [temperature], others might have [pressure]

I want to write a script that reads the temperature data in only, and skips csvs where that column is not present. Unfortunately, it leads to an error when it cannot find the temperature column in some csvs.

These are the things I have tried:

```
file_list<-list.files(path='path', full.names = TRUE, pattern="*.csv")

cind <- c("sensor_id", "sensor_type", "lat", "lon", "timestamp", "temperature")

#attempt 1 - this leads to an undefined columns selected error

collate1 <- lapply(file_list, function(x) read.csv(x, sep=";", header=TRUE)[cind])

#attempt 2 - I try to skip files that lead to an error, but it still has an undefined columns selected error

collate2 <- tryCatch(lapply(file_list, function(x) read.csv(x, sep=";", header=TRUE)[cind]), 
        warning = function(e) print(paste('no temperature')))

#attempt 3 - I try some kind of if statement but I don't quite understand the output

collate3 <- lapply(file_list, function(x){
  df <- read.csv(x, sep=";", header=TRUE)
  df_new <- df[,c("sensor_id", "sensor_type", "lat", "lon", "timestamp")]
  if("temperature" %in% colnames(df)    ){
    return(df_new$temperature == df$temperature)
  } else {return(NA)
  }
})

collate3 <- collate3 [sapply(is.na, collate3 )]
```

There is a very large amount of data, so I would be keen to figure out something that can work quickly.

Thanks

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1: read all files, then filter the list on the presence of `"temperature"`:

```r
file_list <- list.files(path = 'path', full.names = TRUE, pattern = "*.csv")
collate1 <- lapply(file_list, read.csv2)
collate1 <- collate1[sapply(collate1, function(z) "temperature" %in% names(z))]
cind <- c("sensor_id", "sensor_type", "lat", "lon", "timestamp", "temperature")
collate1 <- lapply(collate1, function(z) z[ind])
```

Method 2: if there are too many files, you can determine which files to read by reading only a couple of rows first.

```r
file_list <- list.files(path = 'path', full.names = TRUE, pattern = "*.csv")
collate1 <- lapply(file_list, read.csv2, nrows = 2)
collate1 <- collate1[sapply(collate1, function(z) "temperature" %in% names(z))]
cind <- c("sensor_id", "sensor_type", "lat", "lon", "timestamp", "temperature")
collate1 <- lapply(names(collate1), function(z) read.csv2(z)[cind])
```

Comment: I was going to say that your method 1 might be wasting time reading large files that are ultimately discarded. But your method 2 seems to have that covered - nice one! Plus if the files are small or you aren't discarding many files then method 1 is probably quicker than doing twice as many read operations.

Answer (score 2):

Read in the first row of each file to find out which files you want.

```r
files_to_read_in  <- lapply(file_list, \(f) {
    dat  <- read.csv(f, nrow = 1, sep = ";")
    if(all(cind %in% names(dat))) {
        file_to_read  <- f    
    } else {
        file_to_read  <- NULL
    }
    file_to_read
}
)  |> unlist()
```

Then read in those files:

```r
collate1 <- lapply(files_to_read_in, function(f) read.csv(f, sep=";", header=TRUE)[cind])
```

Comment: This worked really well for me - thanks! By 'work quickly', I meant run through the many gigabytes of csv data. By finding the csvs with the relevant eaders, this really reduced computational demands.

Comment: @Jon how big are the individual files? If more than a few thousand rows you'd probably get a more or less free further boost if you replace your main `lapply()` using `read.csv()` with `lapply(files_to_read_in, \(f) data.table::fread(f, sep = ";", header = TRUE, select = cind))`. If you don't want to return a `data.table` you can also add `data.table = FALSE` to the `fread()` call.

Comment: There are 280 csvs, the largest ones have around 6 million rows (although I haven't checked if the biggest have temperature). So, this change helps even more.